# How to refresh already fetched attribute in EclipseLink

Tags: java, jpa, caching, orm, eclipselink

I am using EclipseLink as an ORM in a project we are developing and I wanted to know how we can refresh data which is already lazy fetched from database and being used in user interface layer. Lets say I have an object "a" and it is holding a reference to a list of object "b".

```
public class A implements java.io.Serializable {
    @OrderBy("id ASC")
    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "a", targetEntity = B.class)
    private List<B> bs = new ArrayList<B>();

    // getter and setters
    public List<B> getBs() {
        return bs;
    }

    public void setBs(List<B> bs) {
        this.bs = bs;
    }
}
```

when I use a.getBs(); for the first time in my user interface layer. It feches all the "b" objects from the database and it is all ok. But when I persist another "b" object which is a child of the "a" object and again call a.getBs(); I am getting the old list of b objects.

İs there a way to configure EclipseLink that each time (or at specific times) I call a.getBs(); I get the updated (current) list oj b objects. In total I want EclipseLink go and ask to the database every time I need this list or I should be saying this to it.

Thanks in advance.
Bye

Edited: My B class definition is something like this:

```
public class IstekGorev implements java.io.Serializable {
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "A", nullable = false)
    private A a;

    // getter and setters
    public IstekTalep getTalep() {
        return talep;
    }

    public void setTalep(IstekTalep talep) {
        this.talep = talep;
    }
}
```

and in the user interface I am doing something like this:

```
List<B> bList = a.getBs();
// show bList in a table
// persist another "b" object which is a child of "a"
// in order to show the user the updated list of "b" objects get "bList" again
List<B> bUpdatedList = a.getBs();
```

in the above situation I always get the old list which means there is no difference between "bList" and "bUpdatedList". How can I say to EclispeLink that it should go and ask the database again when I called the "a.getBs();" second time.

Comment: Can you please show B class definition?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11013623/eclipselink-persistence-and-refresh-both-association-entities

Comment: And this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18817719/jpa-eclipselink-entities-not-refreshing

Comment: As Pringi's posts point out, you likely are not maintaining the collection when you change the reference, which is required in JPA. Your code snippet though could also point ot something else - that you expect JPA to actually fetch you the collection from the database every time you call get. If that is the expectation, you are expecting something very wrong. By mapping the relationship, you are telling JPA to cache it in the object so you can pass it around. But it is cached. If you want it fetched, you need to manually query for it, and might be better off NOT mapping it in your entity.